# Pass data from controller of one app to another controller of anoter app

Tags: angularjs

I want to pass value of App3 (Root app) to other child app but i am not able to do the  same below is the code i am using. Please Help.

I wanted to know that is it possible to write parent ng-app and use the variable of parent ng-app to its child ng-app?

```html
<div id="3">
  <div ng-controller="root">
    {{ abc }}
    <div id="1">
      <div ng-controller="myCrtl">
        <p>{{ flag+" "+abc}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="2">
      <div ng-controller="myCrtl1">
        <p>{{ flag1+" "+flag}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular.js">
</script>
<script>
  var app1 = angular.module('MyApp1', []);

  var app2 = angular.module('MyApp2', ['MyApp1']);

  var app3 = angular.module('MyApp3', ['MyApp1', "MyApp2"]);
  app3.controller('root', function($scope) {
    $scope.abc = "abc";
  });
  app1.controller('myCrtl', function($scope) {
    $scope.flag = "ctr1";
  });

  app2.controller('myCrtl1', function($scope) {
    $scope.flag1 = "ctr2";
  });
  angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('1'), ['MyApp1']);
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('2'), ['MyApp2']);
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('3'), ['MyApp3']);
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you setting this up as 3 apps in the first place and not injecting modules into one main module and having only one app that can share services?

Comment: I know it is possible but wanted to try and learn concept of inheritance. And also wanted to know that is it possible?

Comment: Well quite honestly this approach makes very little sense. What do you expect to inherit when you have all these apps isolated? Angular was not designed for this. It was designed for one app per page and that app can be made up of many modules